# Как открыть и закрыть меню при клике

Tags: javascript, html

Не могу сделать так, чтобы при клике на `.menu-icon` появился меню.

Код:

```js
$('.menu-icon').click( function(){
    if ( $('.s-menu').hasClass('show') ) {
        $('.s-menu').removeClass('show');
    } else {
        $('.s-menu').removeClass('show');
        $('.s-menu').addClass('hide');    
    }
});
```

```css
*{
 box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /*Firefox 1-3*/
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari */
}
div{
 box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /*Firefox 1-3*/
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari */
}
body, html{ 
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 height: 100%;
}
a{
 color: #000;
 text-decoration: none;
}
ul{
 list-style-type: none;
 padding: 0;
}
.hide{
 display: none;
}
.show{
 display: block;
}
/*****Sidebar******/
.container{
 min-height: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
 float: left;
 position: fixed;
}
.sidebar h3{
 font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
 color: #333;
 font-size: 24px;
 padding: 50px 30px 0 30px;
 margin: 0;
}
.sidebar h4{
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 color: #3971ff;
 font-size: 16px;
 padding-left: 30px;
 font-weight: lighter;
}
.sidebar{
 background-color: #f3f3f3;
 border-right: 1px solid #a7a7a7;
}
.s-menu{
 padding-bottom: 9999px;
 margin-bottom: -9999px;
}
.s-menu li{
 padding: 18px 0;
 padding-left: 25px;
 font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #a7a7a7;
 width: 70%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 font-size: 16px;
}
.s-menu li:last-child{
 border: 0;
}
.s-menu a{
 color:#a7a7a7;
 transition: all 0.2s;
}
.left-line{
 width: 14px;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: #3971ff;
 margin-left: -20px;
 margin-top: -10px;
 transition: all 0.2s;
}
.active .left-line{
 width: 28px;
 transition: all 0.2s;
}
.menu-icon{
 display: none;
}
.active a{
 padding-left: 10px;
 transition: all 0.2s;
 color: #4c4c4c;
}
/******Sections*******/
.content{
 max-width: 920px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
/******Section Header*******/
.header {
 background-color: #EAEBED;
 height: 582px;
}
.content img{
 margin: 125px;
}
.header-text{
 margin-top: -450px;
 margin-left: 450px;
}
.header-text h3{
 font-size: 30px;
 margin: 0;
 font-family: 'Exo 2',sans-serif;
 font-weight: lighter;
 color: #4c4c4c;
}
.header-text h1{
 font-size: 48px;
 font-family: 'Exo 2',sans-serif;
 font-weight: lighter;
 color: #4c4c4c;
 margin: 0;
}
.header-text h1 span{
 color: #3971ff;
}
.header-text h4{
 color: #3971ff;
 font-family: 'Roboto',sans-serif;
 font-weight: lighter;
 font-size: 16px;
 border-top: 1px solid #232323;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #232323;
 display: inline-block;
 padding:10px 15px;
}
.header-text p{
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 font-family: 'Roboto',sans-serif;
 font-size: 16px;
 color: #4c4c4c;
 line-height: 28px;
 padding-bottom: 40px;
}
.header-text span{
 color: #3971ff;
}
.header-select{
 font-family: 'Roboto',sans-serif;
 color: #4c4c4c;
 margin-right: 86px;
 font-weight: bold;
 transition: all 0.2s;
 display: inline-block;
}
.header-select:hover{
 color: #3971ff;
 transition: all 0.2s;
}
.down-line{
 width: 50px;
 height: 2px;
 background-color: #3971ff;
 display: block;
 margin-top: 10px; 
 transition: all 0.3s;
 position: absolute;
}
.header-select:hover .down-line{
 width: 120px;
 transition: all 0.3s;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
 .header-text h1{
  font-size: 38px;
 }
 .header-text h3{
  font-size: 22px;
 }
 .header-text h4{
  font-size: 15px;
  padding:5px 10px;
 }
 .header-text p{
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 23px;
  padding-bottom: 35px;
 }
 .content img {
  margin: 172px;
  max-width: 24%;
 }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 991px) {
 .container{
  min-height: 0;
  width: 100%;
 }
 .sidebar h3{
  padding: 10px 0px 0px 20px;
 }
 .sidebar h4{
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  padding-left: 20px;
 }
 .sidebar{
  border: 0; 
 }
 .s-menu {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: -65px;
  line-height:70px;
  text-align: right;
 }
 .left-line{
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #3971ff;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
 }
 .s-menu li {
  border-bottom: 0;
  margin: 0 13px;
  padding: 0;
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 15px;
 }
 /******Sections******/
 .sections{
  padding-top: 71px;
 }
 .content img {
  max-width: 22%;
  margin: 116px 0 100px 60px;
  padding-top: 30px;
 }
 .header-text {
  margin-top: -300px;
  margin-left: 300px;
  padding: 0 20px;
 }
 .header-text h3 {
  font-size: 18px;
 }
 .header-text h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
 }
 .header-text h4 {
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 4px 8px;
 }
 .header-text p {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
 }
 .header-select{
  font-size: 15px;
 }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 820px) {
 .content img {
  max-width: 25%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
 }
 .header-text{
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 50px;
 }
 /*****Menu******/
 .sidebar h4 {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
 }
 .s-menu {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  text-align: left; 
  padding-left: 0;
  display: none;
 }
 .s-menu li {
  border-bottom: 0;
  margin: 20px 20px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 15px;
 }
 .s-menu li:last-child{
  padding-bottom: 15px;
 }
 .left-line {
  width: 25px;
  height: 2px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
 }
 .menu-icon{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 25px;
  cursor: pointer; 
 }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .header-text{
  padding: 10px 20px;
 }
 .header-select{
  display: block;
  margin: 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <h3>AL-RAYHAN</h3>
    <h4>UI & UX Designer</h4>
    <img src="images/menu.png" alt="menu-icon" class="menu-icon">
    <ul class="s-menu">
      <li><a href="#">SKILLS</a>
        <div class="left-line"></div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">EDUCATION</a>
        <div class="left-line"></div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">EXPERIENCE</a>
        <div class="left-line"></div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">PORTFOLIO</a>
        <div class="left-line"></div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">BLOG</a>
        <div class="left-line"></div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">PRICING</a>
        <div class="left-line"></div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a>
        <div class="left-line"></div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Container-->
```

[Код в JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hgkrrznp/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.menu-icon').click( function(){
  $('.s-menu').toggle();
});
```

Не забудьте добавить jQuery в опциях *JAVASCRIPT* - *FRAMEWORKS & EXTENSIONS*.

Comment: Вы ведь видели `.menu-icon{
 display: none;
}`?

Comment: @Other Хм, нет, не видел. А чего ж он виден в правом верхнем углу?

Comment: спс большое за ответ )))

Comment: @Other а, там еще один: `.menu-icon{ display: block; ...`

Comment: я новичок просто немного неправильно делаю многие вещи

Comment: Код там знатный во многом. Просто это сразу в глаза бросилось.